# About reverse inequality :$-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+1}+\sqrt{c^2+a^{2}+b^{2}}\right)\geq c\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}$

Tags: inequality

It's a reverse inequality from a previous post but first the conjecture :

### Conjecture :

Let $a,b,c\in[0,1]$ such that $a\geq b\geq c$ then (dis)prove that :

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(-\sqrt{3}+\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+1}\right)-\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}-\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)(1-a)-\frac{\left(a-b\right)}{13}\leq 0$$

---

---

---

I have check the inequality with the Software Desmos .On the other hand I think that this inequality is interesting because it's non-homegeneous and to go further there is  equality cases for : $a=b=c=0$ or $a=b=c=1$ or $a=b=1$

The first inequality can be found here [Refinement :$\sqrt{3}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}-\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^{2}+\frac{\left(2a-b-c\right)^{2}}{24}}\geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387450/refinement-sqrt3-sqrta2b2c2-sum-cyc-sqrta2-frac-left) at edit 22/02/2022.

To show it I use  Vasc's paper or equal variable method but here it doesn't work because of the last term with the minus .

Edit 03/03/2022:

Denotes by $k(a,b,c)$ the right hand side of the inequality above,I mean the inequality in the conjecture then it seems we have for $a=1$ :

$$k(a,b,c)\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(a+b+c\right)\right)-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(a+b+c\right)-\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\left(1-a\right)=0$$

Where the idea is to use with the constraint above :

$$\sqrt{3}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}-\left(a+b+c\right)\geq 0$$

### Question :

> How to (dis)prove the conjecture ?

Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hum yes .I edit ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See my edit please .Thanks for your comment .

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the inequality in the title has to do with the inequality in the body. Do you want to (dis)prove the title inequality, or the body?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The body let me edit .

Answer (score 1):

It seems we have for $a,b,c\in[0.75,1]$ and $a\geq b \geq c$ :

$$\frac{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+1\right)}{3}-\left(\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\left(1-a\right)+\frac{\left(a-b\right)}{13}+1\right)^{2}\leq 0$$

And :

$$\frac{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+1\right)\left(a^{2}+c^{2}+1\right)}{9}-\frac{\left(\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\left(1-a\right)+\frac{\left(a-b\right)}{13}+1\right)^{2}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}{3}\leq 0$$

And :

$$\frac{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+1\right)\left(a^{2}+c^{2}+1\right)\left(b^{2}+c^{2}+1\right)}{27}-\frac{\left(\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\left(1-a\right)+\frac{\left(a-b\right)}{13}+1\right)^{2}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)^{2}}{9}\leq 0$$

If true we can apply Karamata's inequality with $f(x)=e^x$

Edit 04/03/2022 :

To show the last inequality we can use Buffalo's way (see brilliant maths.org) with the substitution $x,y,z\geq 0$:

$$a=\frac{0.25(x+y+z)}{x+y+z+1}+0.75,b=\frac{0.25(x+y)}{x+y+1}+0.75,c=\frac{0.25x}{x+1}+0.75$$

I have tried with geogebra and the coefficients seems all negatives but unfornatunely I cannot check all the difference expanded .

On the other hand it seems we have a simpler inequality like :

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(3\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{3}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right)}-\sqrt{3}\right)-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}-\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\left(1-a\right)-\frac{\left(a-b\right)}{13}\leq 0$$

For $a\in[0.75,1]$ and $b,c\in[0.55,0.75]$ Where the inequality above comes from an application of Jensen's inequality .

Next for $x\in[0,2y]$ and $0\leq y\leq \frac{1}{2}$ we have the inequality :
$$\frac{\left(1.5+0.5\left(x^{2}+y\right)\right)}{\sqrt{2.25}}-\sqrt{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}\geq 0$$

We can use it with the Buffalo's way always with $0.5\geq a\geq b \geq c\geq 0$ and the constraints above .

Comment: @RiverLi can you confirm my last edit ? Thanks in advance :-).